# Logic math question?

Tags: logic

How do I shorten "(a and b and c) or (a and negation b and c)"? I feel like the answer is easy but I cant seem to grasp which rule I should use.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Use (x and y) or (x and z) equals x and (y or z), and use z or not z equals true, and use x and true equals x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Distributive Property we get: $$(a \land b \land c) \;\lor\; (a \land \neg b \land c) \;=\; (a \land c) \;\land\; (b \lor \neg b)$$
Where $(b \lor \neg b)$ is a tautology, meaning it always evaluates to 1.
Because 1  is the neutral element of an 'and' operation, we can leave it out, giving us: $$a \land c$$

Comment: Brilliant! Just out of curiosity, what is this format of logic signs called?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're just the standard symbols used in boolean algebra. In LaTex it's '\land', '\lor' and '\neg', if that's what you meant.

Comment: After a quick Google search, it appears that you've used the logical notation and I've used a form of the algebraic notation. It's nice to know how the formats are called!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Writing $d$ for ($a$ and $c$), your formula becomes ($d$ and $b$) or ($d$ and not $b$). Can you now simplify this expression?

Answer (score 0):

Using a few [laws of boolean algebra](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_6.html), specifically the **distributive law** and **complement law**, we get:

[image]